# Draw plot for a grouped data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, group-by

I have an issue, I need to draw a plot for a data that contains factory_name and date in format YYYY. I need to have plot which will contain value for each factory_name, sum of parts that was sold/bought and the mean value for each one for each year.

I tried to make it like that:

```
pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),
                index='Year', columns='factory_name', values='Demand').plot()
```

[image]

And this is ok however I do not have the mean value for each factory_name Demand which I could get but only in data frame and I do not know how I can add this results to my plot.

```
df.groupby(['factory_name','Year']).agg(['sum','mean'])
```

[image]

Here is the code to create data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'factory_name' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','B','A','B','A','A','A'],
                   'Year': [2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2003,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003],
                  'Demand': [100,200,-20,40,30,50,100,200,50,-100,40,50]})
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) has an `aggfunc` parameter that can take a list of functions.

Comment: I know but i couldn’t do it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
colors = ["brown", "darkgreen"]

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

for factory, color in zip(df.factory_name.unique(), colors):
    s = df.loc[df.factory_name==factory].groupby("Year").Demand.mean()
    plt.plot(
        s.index,
        s.values,
        color=color,
        linewidth=2,
        alpha=.5,
        label="%s mean"%factory
    )
for factory, color in zip(df.factory_name.unique(), colors):
    s = df.loc[df.factory_name==factory].groupby("Year").Demand.sum()
    plt.plot(
        s.index,
        s.values,
        color=color,
        linewidth=4,
        alpha=.25,
        label="%s sum"%factory
    )
    
plt.ylim(0,500)
plt.xticks(df.Year.unique())

plt.xlabel("year")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

EDIT:
I edited the code in order to expand the figure size and add the legend.

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: I tried your way and it is ok but do you know how I can add legend to each plot? I tried plt.legend() but it showed me names of factory for mean and sum line, not for the values.

Comment: @Ulewsky yes, using `plt.legend` is right, but you have to add labels to the plots. I edited my solution to add the legend. Try it now.